# How to restrict the Security access for Sitecore Contextual ribbons

Tags: security, ribbon

Have created a contextual ribbon and added the same to the standard values of my desired Template. The functionality is working good.  But I wish to restrict the access of this Ribbon to only few users / admin. How to achieve the same?

Comment: create a specific role and add this role to the core item created for ribbon. under the security section , you can add the new role

Answer (score 0):

Able to achieve this, by implementing the QueryState() method in the command class.

Thanks to this blog by John west-https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-the-content-editor-ribbon-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

[image]